# Isomorphism $H_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus F)\cong H_1(F)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

Suppose that $F$ is an orientable, compact, connected surface of genus $g$ with $n$ boundary components, i.e. $F$ can be drawn like this (see Lickorish's 'An introduction to knot theory'): [[link to picture]](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=67b148-1494445403.png).

One can via induction on $n$ show that we have $H_1(F)=\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}$ for the first (singular) homology group.

I will give now the proposition 6.3 from Lickorish's 'An introduction to knot theory' and its proof, my question later refers to the proof.

> **Proposition.** Suppose that $F$ is like above with non-empty boundary, piecewise lineary contained in $\mathbb{S}^3$. Then the homology groups $H_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus F)$ and $H_1(F)$ are isomoprhic, and there is a unique non-singular bilinear form $$\beta:H_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus F)\times H_1(F)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$$ such that $\beta([c],[d])=\text{lk}(c,d)$ for any oriented simple closed curves.

**Proof (only first part).** $F$ is now embedded in $\mathbb{S}^3$. $H_1(F)=\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $\{[f_i]\}$ (see picture).

Let$V$ be a regular neighbourhood of $F$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$, so that $V$ is just a $3$-ball with $(2g+n-1)$ $1$-handles attached. The inclusion of $F$ in $V$ is a homotopy equivalence, and $H_1(\partial V)=\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}\oplus\bigoplus_{2g+n-1}\mathbb{Z}$. For this, generators $\{[f_i']:1\leq i\leq 2g+n-1\}$ and $\{[e_i]:1\leq i\leq 2g+n-1\}$ can be chosen so that each $e_i$ is the boundary of a small disc in $V$ that meets $f_i$ at one point and the inclusion $\partial V\subset V$ induces on homology a map sending $[f_i']$ to $[f_i]$ and $[e_i]$ to zero.

**Questions.** 1) What changes if we embed $F$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$ (and no more in $\mathbb{R}^3)$?

2) What is a *regular* neighbourhood of $F$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$ and why is this just a $3$-ball with $(2g+n-1)$ handles?

3) Why is $\partial V\subset V$ an inclusion? A boundary of a space needn't to be contained in the space.

Comment: Please cite that this proposition and image are from Lickorish, "An Introduction to Knot Theory." (Proposition 6.3)

Comment: Done! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1): this is easy to answer with a Mayer-Vietoris sequence, showing that removal of a single point from a 3-dimensional manifold does not alter the 1st homology.

Question 2): Suppose you are given a manifold $M$ in your case $\mathbb{S}^3$ (more generally you might be given some kind of cell complex, but I'll stick to manifolds for $M$). Suppose also that you are given a finite subcomplex $\Sigma \subset M$. A regular neighborhood $N(\Sigma) \subset M$ of $\Sigma$ is a generalization of a tubular neighborhood of a compact submanifold (with empty boundary). Intuitively the concept is similar, and the key feature from the perspective of homotopy theory is that $N(\Sigma)$ is a compact submanifold-with-boundary that deformation retracts to $\Sigma$.

In your situation, you know that $\Sigma = F$ itself deformation retracts to a graph $\Gamma$ having one vertex and $2g+n-1$ edges. From this you can conclude that $N(\Sigma)$ is not only a regular neighborhood of $F$ but it is also a regular neighborhood of $\Gamma$ (one is applying the uniqueness theorem for regular neighborhoods at this point, similar to the uniqueness theorem for tubular neighborhoods of submanifolds). Finally, by a direct construction you can show that a regular neighborhood of a graph in $\mathbb{S}^3$ having one vertex and $2g+n-1$ edges is a 3-ball with $2g+n-1$ handles.

For question 3), you might be confusing **topological boundary** with **manifold boundary**? In this setting $V$ is a compact manifold-with-boundary, and $\partial V$ denotes its manifold boundary which is a subset of $V$ by definition of manifold boundary.

Comment: to 1)  So you claim that $H_1(\mathbb{S}^3\setminus\{\ast\})\cong H_1(\mathbb{R}^3)$? In what way does this prove that the first homology group of $F$ doesn't change?

Comment: to 2) It is true that homotopy equivalent spaces have same homology groups, it is also true for a space and a deformation retract, i.e. for $F$ and $V$ respective $N(F)$ in your notation? Besides it would be great if you can give fewer details to your statemant that such a regular neighbourhood is a $3$-ball with $2g+n-1$ handles.

Comment: Regarding 1), the statement applies to any 3-manifold, and particular to the 3-manifold $\mathbb{S}^3 \setminus F$. Since $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus F = (\mathbb{S}^3 - \{\infty\}) \setminus F = (\mathbb{S}^3 \setminus F) - \{\infty\}$, it follows that $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus F$ has the same first homology as $(\mathbb{S}^3 \setminus F) - \{\infty\}$ which has the same first homology as $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus F$.

Comment: Regarding 2), deformation retraction is a special case of homotopy equivalence, so yes, every deformation retract of a space $X$ has the same homology groups as $X$.

Comment: As for your other question regarding 2), perhaps a picture might help https://alexsisto.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/handlebody.png

Comment: 2) is clear now, like 3) also. Regarding 1), what exactly have you shown? That the complements of $F$ have same homology group. But what is about F itself? And why do we want to embed $F$ in $\mathbb{S^3}$ here?

Comment: Thanks for the picture by the way!

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you ask "why do we want to embed $F$ in $\mathbb{S}^3$". Is that not the premise of your question 1)?

Comment: It is the premise of the proposition I have cited. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: That's a big question, too much for a comment, but here's a few specific reasons. One is that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not compact but its one point compactification $\mathbb{S}^3$ is compact. Another is that Alexander duality holds in $\mathbb{S}^3$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Another is the complement of a compact knot or surface in $\mathbb{S}^3$ has contractible universal cover but the complement in $\mathbb{R}^3$ does not. Perhaps what these add up to is that studying objects in $\mathbb{S}^3$ is often simpler than studying objects in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Thank you! That are enough reasons for me :) I have thought about the formula for $H_1(\partial V)$ is the start question and the rest 'one can chose such generators such that...'. Do you may explain what is the reason for this (for the formula and for the choice of the generators)?

Comment: The choice of generators is again best explained with pictures, which are not hard to draw. For example, take the standard picture for generators of $H_1(\partial V)$ in the case of genus 2 https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Philip_Argyres/publication/228540074/figure/fig2/AS:340624533409793@1458222625037/Figure-7-A-genus-2-Riemann-surface-with-a-canonical-homology-basis-of-a-and-b-cycles.png, and superimpose it on the previous picture linked in my earlier comment.

Comment: So you consider the example $g=2$ and $n=1$? But in that case the direct sum of $H_1(\partial V)$ has $8$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$. In your picture I only see $4$ generators. I am a bit lost. Where do we use the fact that $H_1(F)=H_1(V)$? And how are the $f'_i$'s refered to the generators of $F$, i.e. the $f_i$'s?

Comment: No, that link shows the case when $\partial V$ has genus $2$, arising from the case $g=1$ and $n=1$.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit, and here I am simply following the formulas in your question as explained in my earlier comments: in this example $F$ has genus $g=1$ with $n=1$ hole, its regular neighborhood $V$ is a ball with $2=2g+n-1$ handles attached, and the boundary of its regular neighborhood $\partial V$ is a closed surface of genus $2$ (a "double torus", if you like).

Comment: At first I want really say thank you to you because of your patience, super helpful pictures and nice explanations! Secondly, it is possible (in the $g=n=1$ case if you like) to give a picture of the $e_i,f_i,f'_i$'s in the wanted orientation?

Comment: Here's a not-so-great picture, but the best I can find. It shows two views of a one-holed torus ($g=n=1$) embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19nBK.png. Now imagine thickening it, and from the 2nd picture you might be able to see that the result of thickening is a ball with 2 handles attached.

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. From this picture I can see the generators $f_1, f_2$ (notation like in my linked picture resp. in my cited proof). This one-hole torus is now our $F$. Our $V$ is a $3$-ball with $2$ handles, in the notation there are generators $f_1'.f_2',e_1,e_2$. A picture with three properties would be great: 1) It shows $F$, 2) it shows $V$, 3) it shows all the $6$ generators $e_1,e_2,f_1,f_2,f_1',f_2'$. Is this possible?

Comment: So I guess there isn't such a picture resp. it is impossible or very ugly to draw such one?

Comment: It's far from impossible, it could be quite pretty. Perhaps you could do it. Or, perhaps you could ask for that picture in another question, since it goes beyond the bounds of the current question.

Comment: Well, unfortunatly I don't know how to draw this picture and I guess it would help my understanding. It has something to do with that question since I wanted to understand the proof :) Would it be much work for you drawing such a picture? If so, I will start a new question. Thanks for you help so far, that helped a lot.